# Can I have a Twitter account for personal life and one for work?

Tags: networking, social-media

Working as a software developer I feel the need to create a Twitter account for networking purposes.

Actually I already have a Twitter account, I use it only to comment in real time some motorsports events (mainly the 24 Hours of Le Mans) and I want to keep it focused on car racing, for me the 24 Hours of Le Mans is a special time of the year and I have a lot of great memories connected to that account (conversations with other fans during the races, times where my tweets were read and answered live by TV commentators, amazing race situations...) and I don't want to see these memories submerged by "cold" tweets about this programming language or that cloud service so I considering to create a second, work focused account.

Can I do it without worrying or it's considered bad practice?

Comment: "considered bad practice?" - who are you worried will see this as a bad practice? (e.g. your manager, your colleagues, the twitter community)

Comment: Yes, yes you can

Comment: @Bilkokuya I'm worried that my peers might see it as bad practice but from what I'm reading I'm wrong.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that Twitter explicitly allows multiple accounts and [has tools to help you manage them](https://help.twitter.com/en/managing-your-account/managing-multiple-twitter-accounts). This is in contrast to some other social media platforms which don't allow (or at least don't encourage) multiple accounts. Also, now I'm just dying to know what team(s) you support for Le Mans but I guess that's somewhat off topic for The Workplace!

Comment: Thanks for the link @dwizum, regarding Le Mans I gladly take the risk of losing points for a small OT: on LMP1 class I rooted for Porsche from 2014 to 2017 and for Toyota #8 (I'm a big fan of Fernando Alonso) on 2018 and 2019 while on GTE classes I've always rooted for AF Corse.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can (and you should) create a separate account to use in a professional manner (in work context). Many people handle multiple accounts to keep their personal and professional life separate in social media - it's not uncommon.

From Comment: [Twitter seem to allow and encourage having multiple accounts](https://help.twitter.com/en/managing-your-account/managing-multiple-twitter-accounts).

Answer (score 4):

Not only acceptable, it's advisable. It is also allowed by Twitter- their page has tips on managing multiple accounts.

For your personal account, don't put anything in the bio or make tweets that identify your employer. That way if you do tweet about something controversial, you are speaking for you, not your employer.